# Error preparing array in php to use in query in

Tags: javascript, php

I send the array with getJSON like this:

```
$.getJSON('valreceber1.php?arr'+ '&arr=' + arr, function (data6) {
});
```

Where the array is returned this way, when I do `var_dump`:

```
$id_utt1 = $_GET['arr'];
var_dump($id_utt1);
```

Data looks like this:

```
arr: 
arr: 602,602,602,755,602,602,602
```

When I apply this line of code, I always get an error:

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($id_utt1) - 1) . '?';
```

How can I solve?

Comment: As a separate thing, you may want to use `array_unique()` on the array to remove the duplicates (won't stop it working, just less for SQL to check)

Answer (score 0):

In your call to the PHP code, you are creating a blank element as you add the same variable in twice (`arr`)...

```
$.getJSON('valreceber1.php?arr'+ '&arr=' + arr, function (data6) {
});
```

This will mean that, as you can see there are two elements instead of just the one.

So firstly -

```
$.getJSON('valreceber1.php?arr=' + arr, function (data6) {
});
```

This is also giving you a string of comma separated numbers and not an array of values, so use something like `explode()` to split it into an array...

```
$id_utt1 = explode(',', $_GET['arr']);
```